# How can I share the login status using Provider?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I am trying to share the login status using Provider.

```
main.dart

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ChangeNotifierProvider(
    create: (context) => AuthMethod(),
    child: MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'NotoSansKR'),
      home: const AuthScreen(),
    ),
  );
}
```

```
class _AuthScreenState extends State<AuthScreen> {

  final AuthMethod _authMethod = AuthMethod();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final AuthMethod _authProvider = Provider.of<AuthMethod>(context);
    return Scaffold(

.
.
.

if (_authProvider.loginPlatform == LoginPlatform.kakao) ... [
                  Text('kakao login'),
                ] else if (_authProvider.loginPlatform == LoginPlatform.naver) ... [
                  Text('naver login'),
                ] else ... [
                  Text('not loggedin')
                ]
```

The variable '_authMethod' is used for button onpressed.

So I create the variable '_authProvider' to use Provider.

```
class AuthMethod with ChangeNotifier {

  String? accessToken;
  String? tokenType;
  String? refreshToken;

  LoginPlatform _loginPlatform = LoginPlatform.none;
  LoginPlatform get loginPlatform => _loginPlatform;

  void signInWithNaver() async {
    try{
      final NaverLoginResult user = await FlutterNaverLogin.logIn();
      NaverAccessToken res = await FlutterNaverLogin.currentAccessToken;

      setState(() {
        accessToken = res.accessToken;
        tokenType = res.tokenType;
        refreshToken = res.refreshToken;
        _loginPlatform = LoginPlatform.naver;
      });

      String name = user.account.name;
      String email = user.account.email;
      String gender = user.account.gender;
      String birthdate = '${user.account.birthyear}${user.account.birthday}'.replaceAll('-', '');
      String tel = user.account.mobile
          .replaceAll('+82', '0')
          .replaceAll('-', '')
          .replaceAll(' ', '')
          .replaceAll('+', '');

      print('$name, $email, $gender, $birthdate, $tel');

    } catch(error){
      print('naver login error $error');
    }

    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setState(VoidCallback callback) {
      callback();
      notifyListeners();
  }
```

It is a code of naver_login api, and I logged in, but the text doesn't change to 'naver login'.

How can I change 'not login' to 'naver login'?

And am I using Provider correctly now?